# Как сделать элемент Datetime с маской

Tags: c#, wpf, дата, ui

Как можно сделать элемент ***DateTime*** в ***WPF***, так чтобы не надо было вводить вручную точки. С маской какой-то например. 
Дабы ввод даты был быстрее, только цифрами.

Comment: А почему бы вам не воспользоваться `DateTimePicker`ом для таких целей? Оный можно найти, например, в [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).

Comment: Да там много чего удобнее. Но дату нормально все равно не ввести, без ввода точки

Comment: `MaskedTextBox` возьмите